# How to change default line color in highchart stock GUI tools?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to Highchart and right now I am using Highstock GUI tools. It looks like this:
[image: highstock-gui-tools]

So is there any way to change default black line color?

Comment: what did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the default line colors by:

```
navigation: {
    bindings: {
        measureXY: {
            annotationsOptions: {
                typeOptions: {
                    crosshairX: {
                        fill: 'blue',
                        stroke: 'red'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a6on7qyw/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigation.bindings.measureXY

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/annotations.measure.typeOptions.crosshairX